# Why can I not delete forms via paperclip after migrating to bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

We are using paperclip to handle the storage of our forms which are mostly pdf's and before we went to bootstrap you just click delete and then you confirmed and it was gone. But now when we click delete it just takes us to the edit page for the particular form. You have 2 options to edit or go back. I do not know if the code needs to be edited for bootstrap or what the issue is

```
 app/controllers/printed_forms_controller.rb

 # DELETE /printed_forms/1
  # DELETE /printed_forms/1.json
  def destroy
    @printed_form = PrintedForm.find(params[:id])
    @printed_form.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to printed_forms_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
```